# Creating specific layout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-gridview

How can I create this specific layout

[image: Layout]
I need GridView with two colums, but first row should be like this. How can change first row of GridView. Or there is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :-

create DemoActivity.java

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.custom_header1, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(DemoActivity.this );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }}
```

create MySimpleAdapter.java

```
public class MySimpleAdapterextends BaseAdapter{
private  Context context;


public MySimpleAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_header2, parent, false);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}}
```

create main.xml :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

create custom_header1.xml :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

create custom_header2.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first row should not look like the rest of the grid, I would just add it as an own layout element on top of the grid, like a header.

Comment: But I want that "header" to scroll with ListView